# Any way to do "backend media queries" with JS and PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, media-queries

The project I am working on consists of a grid showing content. I would like to resize each item on the grid to a fourth of the viewport's size. This would be very easy with Javascript, but there is some backend stuff that needs to be aware of the size of each item:

I am using Timthumb to resize the image of item to its appropiate size, so I would need to detect the viewport's width, and send the appropiate value (the viewport's width / 4) to the php that serves each item, so it tells Timthumb the appropiate size to use.

What would be the best approach to this problem?

Comment: You'd need JS to send `screen.width` and `screen.height` back to the server. It is otherwise impossible for PHP to know anything about the browser's sizing.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was wondering what the best way of dealing with that us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about when requesting the page, in $(document).ready, detect the size of viewport using jQuery and pass it in an AJAX request?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: image.php,
        data: {
            "height": height,
            "width": width
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#viewarea").html(data);
        },
    });
});
```

at PHP side you can just get it and return the data

```
$_POST['height']
$_POST['width']
```

Comment: By the way you can use http://jquery.malsup.com/block/ to show a loading screen while AJAX is waiting for the server reply

Answer (score 1):

Surely a simple AJAX/JQuery request to the PHP script which generates the image would work here?

Something like:

```
var query_string = "x=<viewport-x>&y=<viewport-y>";
$('#viewport').html("Processing...");
$('#viewport').load('resize_image.php',query_string);
```

That way you just need to take the `$_GET['x']` and `$_GET['y']` vars in your PHP script and pass them to TimThumb before echoing the correct image path back to the page.

Comment: I was thinking of something along these lines, but this would need to happen in the homepage, so how do I make sure that all of this happens before the user sees any content? Would I need to use some kind of preloader page or something?

Comment: you could use the onLoad function of the body tag but that would delay your page from loading whilst the images were processed.

The other way to do it would be to have a"placeholder" image which gets replaced by the resized image once it is available.