# Can I pass different parameters to my php function depending on CSS3 media queries?

Tags: php, css, media-queries

I have a php function 'limitWords' to limit words of text that is coming from database.

When I call this function I need to pass the number of characters I want to show: `lmWord($readDatabase['content'],300)`

It is possible execute this function in different way, depending on width of device? Because, Im using media queries in my project, and I want to execute my limitWords() function in different way for differentes media queries.

For example for mobile, I don't want 300 characters, I want  150. It is possible do this?

Comment: yes, but not based on cssmedia, you could check for devise specific headers to 'guess'

Comment: The only information PHP has about the client is what's in the User Agent string.

Comment: Or maybe via CSS + JS

Comment: This is a job for a client side language (js) not serverside - viewports can change without a page refresh

Comment: you may get the values with JS then you can make ajax request for proper php function

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to do "backend media queries" with JS and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862252/any-way-to-do-backend-media-queries-with-js-and-php)

Comment: Maybe you could delegate that logic to the client side. Give the "longest" case and cut the text node to appropiate size with script.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, Im seeing that I need to solve my problem not thinking in php but in javascript! Thank you!